# RadListView SelectedIndexChanged is firing each time a new item is added

Tags: c#, selectedindexchanged, radlistview

I have a problem with RadListView for C# Winforms that if I add 300 items to the listview the SelectedIndexChanged is firing 300 times.
  What can I do to make it stay selected on the first item and not fire every time a new item is added? Because it selects every time the last item.

This is the add code:

```
 this.lstFileList.Items.Add(item);
```

Comment: Simple, but kind of dirty code: remove the event handler ( -=SelectIndexChanged) before adding new items and attach again if the RadListView is populated.

Comment: thanks, this will be the last solution in case I will not find another one.

Comment: Are you using telerik winforms or asp.net?

Comment: Another solution is to use a boolean (e.g. bool dontFireEvent = false) and set it to true as soon as you add new items. Inside the SelectIndexChanged event you can check the boolean. If it is true ignore the rest of the code, otherwise execute the code.

Comment: I have been thinking about this, but I thought there is a more simple solution, like setting the selected item to none and remain like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding them one at a time, you can bind directly to an `IEnumerable` using the `DataSource` property.

Comment: this way I have problems rebinding the datasource, it stays the same when I change the folder and the file list changes.

Comment: @MarioM I'm going to assume you solved your problem since you marked it as answered, probably because `DataBind()` needed to be called?

Comment: no, the winforms version does not have a databind() function, but I have made an empty List<> which I have set to listview as datasource and then after the original list was changed I have set it back as datasource, this way it got updated.